# Obter os cookies de uma sessão iniciada com HTTPClient no android

Tags: java, android, cookies

Eu faço um post com android e HttpClient em uma pagina, mas preciso saber uma forma de obter os cookies dessa conexão.

esse é o código que utilizo para fazer o post

```
public static void postData(Activity activity, String user, String password) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost([URL]);

    try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", user));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Senha", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        System.out.println("response:" + response);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(responseString);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        System.out.println("ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar `HttpContext`. Atribua um `CookieStore` ao contexto e passe junto com o `HttpPost` no método `execute`.

Exemplo: (Código completo [aqui](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpclient/trunk/httpclient/src/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomContext.java))

```
   // Cria uma instância local do cookie store
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

    // Cria um contexto HTTP local
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    // Junte o cookie store com o contexto
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/"); 

    System.out.println("executing request " + httpget.getURI());

    // Passe o contexto local como parâmetro
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
```

Fonte: [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3587332/520779). Além de atribuir cookies como no exemplo acima, você pode ler de volta os cookies atribuídos pelo servidor. Para passá-los novamente numa nova requisição, é só reutilizar o objeto `HttpContext` criado em novas requisições.

Comment: Era o que eu precisava! Valeu mesmo!