# Android - Cookie HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, cookies, webview, http-headers, autenticação-http

Tenho uma tela de login nativa no android, que o usuário insere login e senha, ae faz uma verificação via HttpURLConnection se os dados estão corretos, se sim então ele salva o cookie, e retorna que o login foi efetuado, em seguida é chamado uma webview desse servidor, porém quando chama o webview está aparecendo que o usuário não está logado, ou seja, os cookies não ficaram armazenados. Existe alguma propriedade a ser configurada no HttpURLConnection para que esses cookies fiquem salvo para uma webview?

Comment: essa pagina eh carregada da web neh? nao esta dentro do app android?

Comment: A tela é carregada dentro de uma webview dentro do app.

Comment: nessa resposta [http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12302/obter-os-cookies-de-uma-sess%C3%A3o-iniciada-com-httpclient-no-android?rq=1] eh atribuido um CookieStore, isso deve solucionar.